# How to read csv data, strip spaces/tabs and write to new csv file?

Tags: python, csv, read-write

I have a large (1.6million rows+) .csv file that has some data with leading spaces, tabs, and trailing spaces and maybe even trailing tabs. I need to read the data in, strip all of that whitespace, and then spit the rows back out into a new .csv file preferably with the most efficient code possible and using only built-in modules in python 3.7

Here is what I have that is currently working, except it only spits out the header over and over and over and doesn't seem to take care of trailing tabs (not a huge deal though on trailing tabs):

```py
def new_stripper(self, input_filename: str, output_filename: str):
    """
    new_stripper(self, filename: str):
    :param self: no idea what this does
    :param filename: name of file to be stripped, must have .csv at end of file
    :return: for now, it doesn't return anything...


    -still doesn't remove trailing tabs?? But it can remove trailing spaces
    -removes leading tabs and spaces
    -still needs to write to new .csv file
    """
    import csv
    csv.register_dialect('strip', skipinitialspace=True)
    reader = csv.DictReader(open(input_filename), dialect='strip')
    reader = (dict((k, v.strip()) for k, v in row.items() if v) for row in reader)
    for row in reader:
        with open(output_filename, 'w', newline='') as out_file:
            writer = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter=',')
            writer.writerow(row)


input_filename = 'testFile.csv'
output_filename = 'output_testFile.csv'
new_stripper(self='', input_filename=input_filename, output_filename=output_filename)
```

As written above, the code just prints the headers over and over in a single line. I've played around with the arrangement and indenting of the last four lines of the def with some different results, but the closest I've gotten is getting it to print the header row again and again on new lines each time:

```py
...
    # headers and headers for days
    with open(output_filename, 'w', newline='') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

EDIT1: Here's the result from the non-stripping correctly thing. Some of them have leading spaces that weren't stripped, some have trailing spaces that weren't stripped. It seems like the left-most column was properly stripped of leading spaces, but not trailing spaces; same with header row.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4D8t2.png)

***Update: Here's the solution I was looking for:***

```py
def get_data(self, input_filename: str, output_filename: str):
    import csv
    with open(input_filename, 'r', newline='') as in_file, open(output_filename, 'w', newline='') as out_file:
        r = csv.reader(in_file, delimiter=',')
        w = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter=',')
        for line in r:
            trim = (field.strip() for field in line)
            w.writerow(trim)


input_filename = 'testFile.csv'
output_filename = 'output_testFile.csv'

get_data(self='', input_filename=input_filename, output_filename=output_filename)
```

Comment: Do you have to use python, or can you use something faster and efficient, like `awk` or `sed`?

Comment: I could use something else, but I'm trying to automate this since it will have to be done again and again on a monthly basis and I'll need to do some calculations on the data after cleaning it

Comment: See my updated answer for a solution using `sed`.

Comment: Thing is I don't have admin privileges on the computer where this work has to be done... will that require such access? I have no experience using shells

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't make life complicated for yourself, "CSV" files are simple plain text files, and can be handled in a generic way:

```
with open('input.csv', 'r') as inf, open('output.csv', 'w') as of:
    for line in inf:
        trim = (field.strip() for field in line.split(','))
        of.write(','.join(trim)+'\n')
```

Alternatively, using the `csv` module:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', 'r') as inf, open('output.csv', 'w') as of:

    r = csv.reader(inf, delimiter=',')
    w = csv.writer(of, delimiter=',')

    for line in r:
        trim = (field.strip() for field in line)
        w.writerow(trim)
```

Comment: That worked, but it didn't strip the white space from everything

Comment: Can you give an example line or file which did not get stripped properly? `str.strip()` strips spaces, tabs and newlines from both ends of the string.

Comment: Given the nature of the data I can't publish it online, but I did a mockup and made sure to only replace letters/numbers with random jibberish and re-ran the code. Wish I could post the actual .csv output but I will append the original post... give me a minute then refresh

Comment: Oh, I see, you want to strip the whitespace per field. Sorry, I will post a new solution.

Comment: Please check the answer for the new solution.

Comment: Bingo! Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I cannot comment, but I believe you might want to strip every entry in csv of the white space (not just the line). If that is the case, then, based on Jan's answer, this might do the trick:

```
with open('file.csv', 'r') as inf, open('output.csv', 'w') as of:
    for line in inf:
        of.write(','.join(list(map(str.strip, line.split(',')))) + '\n')
```

What it does is it splits each line by comma resulting in a list of values, then strips every element from whitespace to later join them back up and save to output file.

Answer (score 0):

your final reader variable contains tuple of dicts but your writer expects list.

you can either user csv.DictWriter or store the processed data(v) in a list first and then write to csv and include headers using writer.writeheader()