# Extract data from csv ignoring spaces in header

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv in my project folder(file2.csv). But here the "Name" column has a space "Name " as shown. But while extracting the file, can we ignore the white spaces.

```
data2 = {'Name ' : ['Tom', 'Nick', 'Tom'], 'Cat' : ['xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz']}
d2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

So while extracting the file using below code

```
asd = pd.read_csv('datafiles/file2.csv', nrows=1, usecols=["Name"])
ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: ['Name']
```

I get above error since "Name" is not there instead "Name " is there. So inspite of the spaces, can we make sure even if I give "Name" the file should be extracted?

Note : Actual data is in csv format in my project folder and d2 here is just for your reference

However I tried with below code, but I get error

```
In [55]: df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep = '|', usecols=lambda x : x.strip() in "Name")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "‹ipython-input-55-016ee29c65e6›", line 1, in ‹modules
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep = '|', usecols=lambda x : x.strip() in "Name")
File "C: \Program Files \Anaconda2\lib\site-packages \pandas\io\parsers.py", line 562, in parser_f return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
File "C: \Program Files \Anaconda2\lib\site-packages \pandas \io\parsers.py", line 315, in _read
parser = TextFileReader (filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
File "C: \Program Files \Anaconda2\lib\site-packages \pandas \io\parsers.py", line 645, in _ self._make_engine (self.engine)
アー
File "C: \Program Files \Anaconda2\lib\site-packages \pandas\io\parsers.py", line 799, in _make_engine
self._engine = CarserWrapper (self.f, **self.options)
File "C: \Program Files \Anaconda2\lib\site-packages \pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1213, in _ init
self._reader = _parser. TextReader (sc, **kwds)
File "pandas \parser.pyx", line 417, in pandas.parser. TextReader._ cinit_ (pandas\parser.c: 3977)
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *Callable* with [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) in `usecols` :

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", usecols=lambda x: x.strip() in ["Name"])
```

​
Output :

```
print(df)

  Name 
0   Tom
1  Nick
2   Tom
```

Input used (*.csv*) :

```
Name ,Cat
Tom,xxx
Nick,yyy
Tom,zzz
```

Comment: Hi . I tried this, But I get error ````'function' object is not iterable'````

Comment: You need to show you full code/error because I can't reproduce the issue with the csv in my answer.

Comment: oops.. I am not able to share the pic here in comment. Is there a way to share?

Comment: You can copy/paste it in your question/post above.

Comment: First, there is syntax error (*a typo*), you need to use `lambda x: ...` and not `lambda ×: ...`. Second, you need to enclose `"Name"` between square brackets `["Name"]`.

Comment: What? I have used ````lambda x:```` only :) I just copy pasted your code only

Comment: I copy/pasted the code from your traceback error and I got a `SyntaxError`. Please, re-check your code.

Comment: No dear. I checked the code  and its correct as you suggested. Fine, i edited my code

Comment: I can't help you if you insist that there is no `SyntaxError` in your code.

Comment: fine. Is there any other method I can try?

Comment: You need to **1)** share a reproducible example of your `file.txt`, **2)** show your code (*not just the traceback error*) and **3)** indicate which pandas version you're using `print(pd.__version__)`.

Comment: pd version is 0.18.1

Comment: `pandas 0.18.1` was released (7 years ago!) in [May 3, 2016](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.18.1.html). Try to update it `pip install --upgrade pandas`.

Answer (score 1):

You can first try to remove the blanks, so that you give it a general formatting and thus avoid future errors in the operation.

You can rely on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57394274/7972386) answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is almost same with : [Python: Editing Dictionary Keys - Using Strip Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58551714/python-editing-dictionary-keys-using-strip-method)

In short:
`data2 = {k.strip(): v for (k, v) in data2.items()}`

Hope that helps.